# Why isn't this C# code working? It should return the string between two other strings, but always returns an empty string

Tags: c#, string

The title explains it all.  It seems simple enough, so I must be overlooking something stupid.  Here's what I've got.

```
    private string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
    {
        int start, end;
        if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
        {
            start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
            end = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, start);
            return strSource.Substring(start, end - start);
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Thanks, guys.

Comment: What are the values you are testing with?

Comment: Have you run it in a debugger?  With what input?  What values do you get for start and end?  What values did you *expect* to get?

Comment: tell us the call method code, the test line you use

Comment: I've tried it with many things, and results are always the same.  Simply trying getBetween("1234, "1", "4") returns an empty string.  I am expecting to get a "23" back.

Comment: What values for the variables `start` and `end` did you get?  Those are the variables that matter.  Use a debugger!

Comment: I just tried calling getBetween("123", "1", "3") and it returned 2.  Your code seems right.

So check your string and also check the encoding on your strings.  You might need to use StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase in the Contains and IndexOf functions.

Comment: What is the 2nd argument to IndexOf(), and why is it different for the 2 calls?

Comment: I Think the code is right, the problem may be in values you send, and may add more check for start less than end, to confirm that you are sending values right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As couple of peoples said the problem that you code is working on very specific input, it's all because of this start and end IndexOf magic =) But when you try to update you code to work correct on more inputs you will get into problem that your code become very long with many indexes, comparsions, substrings, conditions and so on. To avoid this i like to recommend you use **regular expressions** with theirs help you can express what you need on special language.

Here is the sample which solves your problem with regular expressions:

```
        public static string getBetween(string source, string before, string after)
        {
            var regExp = new Regex(string.Format("{0}(?<needle>[^{0}{1}]+){1}",before,after));
            var matches = regExp.Matches(source).Cast<Match>(). //here we use LINQ to
                OrderBy(m => m.Groups["needle"].Value.Length).  //find shortest string
                Select(m => m.Groups["needle"].Value);          //you can use foreach loop instead
            return matches.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

All tricky part is `{0}(?<needle>[^{0}{1}]+){1}` where 0 - before string and 1 - after string. This expression means that we nned to find string that lies beetween 0 and 1, and also don't contains 0 and 1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Regular expressions are their own problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't make sure that start and end are in order.

```
static string SubString(string source, string prefix, string suffix)
{
    int start = source.IndexOf(prefix); // get position of prefix
    if (start == -1)
        return String.Empty;
    int subStart = start + prefix.Length; // get position of substring
    int end = source.IndexOf(suffix, subStart); // make sure suffix also exists
    if (end == -1)
        return String.Empty;
    int subLength = end - subStart; // calculate length of substring
    if (subLength == 0)
        return String.Empty;
    return source.Substring(subStart, subLength); // return substring
}
```

Comment: @RitchMelton his code is wrong. Contains doesn't ensure that start and end strings will be in order.

Comment: You would have been better off _explaining_ that in your answer rather than just dumping some code and expecting OP to work it out. In any case, that doesn't explain why `getBetween("1234","1","4")` doesn't work since that _clearly_ doesn't invoke the "start > end" problem.

Comment: Okay, something weird is definitely going on here... I get the exact same problem with your code as I do with mine.  Other people seem to be using both just fine, so it must be me or my machine.  What would cause this problem?  It returns as if source doesn't contain prefix and/or suffix, but when tested for truth value manually, both do.

I'm stumped guys, what could cause this?

Comment: Hmmm, it appears that with this code it thinks that (end == -1) is true, even when it is _clearly_ there...

Comment: enkrypt0r...do you have some sort of locale configured?

Answer (score 1):

I get the correct answer if I try any of these:

```
var a = getBetween("ABC", "A", "C");
var b = getBetween("TACOBBURRITO", "TACO", "BURRITO");
var c = getBetween("TACOBACONBURRITO", "TACO", "BURRITO");
```

The problem is likely with your input argument validation, as this fails:

```
var a = getBetween("ABC", "C", "A");
var a = getBetween("ABC", "C", "C");
```

You can improve your validation of the issue by writing some test cases like these as a separate fixture (xUnit, or main loop in throw away app).